# Rewrite url only if a specific word is not url

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect url having a number at the end of the url to another url.

```
http://localhost:8080/bangalore/khano-khajano-mg-road-1


RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^-].+[0-9])$ ${restrenamemap:$1_$2_info} [L,R=301]
```

But, this matches following url also.

```
http://localhost:8080/noida/restaurants/sector-1
```

How can I tell mod_rewrite not to rewrite url, if there are restaurants after the first slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
^/([^/]+)/(?!restaurants)([^-].+[0-9])$
```